# How to shorten a list of variable names in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, environment-variables

In a shell script, I have a list of variables that I've ordered as $a, $b, $c, etc. I'd like to print these variables without having to list all the variables. My current code is as follows:

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
d=4
e=5
f=6
g=7

for x in $a$b$c$d$e$f$g
do
  echo "$x"
done
```

Can I shorten $a$b$c$d$e$f$g to something that refers to $a through $g?

Comment: Do you realize `echo` will run just once? Why `for` then? Is it because some characters in variables (`c=" "` or `d=" /* "`) can make it run more than once? This only makes the code more awkward. Is this really what you want to do?

Comment: Not necessarily. I'm just trying to understand how to shorten the line $a$b$c$d$e$f$g and wanted to provide an example. I wouldn't necessarily need the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "evil" `eval`:

```
eval echo \"$(printf '$%s' {a..g})\"
```

Note that I used escaped quotes which is needed for correct output if your variables should contain space characters.

Or use the corrected for-loop of the [first answer](https://superuser.com/a/1452472/990044):

```
for x in {a..g}; do printf "${!x}"; done
```

Or use an array in your script. It's a different syntax, but is easier to handle if you need all values at once. Here's a small example:

```
array=(1 2 3 4 x 6)
array+=(7)  # add one more
array[4]=5  # modify element at index 4
printf '%s' "${array[@]}"
```

Note that the last two `printf` statements don't end with a newline.